# Database Scheme for User made Online Election

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently working on a web project "Online Election" where users can create Election as they need.
I can not think of any idea how the Database should be, For the database, every time user create an election should the system create new required table for the election or I could just some tables to hold everything ?

1. case 1 (create required table for each election ) :

- user_table (id,name,email,etc)
- election_table (user_id, election_id,etc)

per election created by user above, below tables will be created in database with electionId is part of table name :

- voter_electionId_table (voter_id,name,email,etc)
- candidate_electionId_table (candidate_id,no,name)
- ballot_electionId_table(vote_id,candidate_id)

2. case 2 ( same tables for every election) :

- user_table (id,name,email,etc)
- election_table (user_id, election_id,etc)
- voter(voter_id,election_id,etc)
- candidate_electionId_table (electionID,candidate_id,no,name,etc)
- ballot_electionId_table(electionId,vote_id,candidate_id)

which from above is better ? or none of them is good (If yes, please share your thought).

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck/unsure on what step following what published textbook/presentation of what method/process?

Answer (score 0):

You would have an election table where you at the bare minimum would have

election(id, creator_id)

where creator_id is the user's id, a foreign key to the user. You can add other attributes, like name, country (or country_id?), date, etc.

Comment: i've edited my question, would you mind to check it again ?

Comment: @xedox_za your question in its current form is opinionated. You need to ask factual questions, so instead of "which is better" you need to ask "how can I achieve this" types of questions.